# vala: convenient way of getting properties

Tags: vala

I know that one can set a property of a GLib.Object-based class by name using the following simple syntax

```
obj["foo"] = bar;
```

Is there a way to get the property's value in the similar way? The following construction doesn't seem to work:

```
Bar bar = obj["foo"];
```

Vala returns *error: invocation of void method not allowed as expression*

I know it can be done as in the example below, but I'm looking for something conciser.

```
Bar bar;
obj.get("foo", out bar);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Bar bar = obj.foo;
```

You should use similar code to set properties, too, instead of what you wrote above:

```
obj.foo = bar;
```

It's not usually a big deal, but that form tends to be a bit more efficient than going through GObject properties. And it's shorter. IMHO it looks better, too.

Comment: But what if B is a subclass of A and I want to get property of B having a reference to A?

Comment: `(obj as B).foo`. Or `((B) obj).foo`, if you prefer.